# Pros and cons of sdist

Tags: python, python-packaging

What are the pros and cons of packaging a Python project using `python setup.py sdist`, taking care of listing all files in MANIFEST.in instead of just creating an archive of the whole project tree?

Creating an archive of the tree sounds simpler and less error-prone to me, but maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, `sdist` creates a `PKG-INFO` file inside the archive. This file can be used by tools such as pip to know more about the package. Its content is a set of `<key>: <value>` lines defined here: https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/.

It is basically a declarative version of the metadata provided to the call to `setup()` in the `setup.py`.

I haven't tried to upload a package built without a PKG-INFO file to PyPI, but I suspect it would fail because of the lack of PKG-INFO file.